# How do I make a loaded .txt file include the increments in text between lines?

Tags: javascript

Using the following code, I'm loading a local file on a webserver and printing its result to a `<p>` tag, but when I load the file it just dumps all the text onto the page without any consideration to the gaps between lines, it includes the spaces between words but not lines, making it look extremely messy and unreadable (as an Admin

```
setInterval(function readFile() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/logs.txt');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = client.responseText;
    }
    client.send();
    }, 1);
```

Is there any way I can include the gaps between lines?

Comment: Send a HTML string instead of plain text.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that with client.responseText ? Relatively new to JS

Comment: You don't, that's something you do at the server-side. At client-side you can edit the returned text, something like `html = client.responseText.replace(/\r\n|\n/g, '<br>');`.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this would be to use a `<pre>` instead of a `<p>`, where `\n` linefeeds will be considered meaningful. It changes the styling too though.

Comment: Thanks, <pre> worked perfectly. The styling doesn't matter since it's just a log, +1

Comment: Instead of dumping into a `<p>`, dump into `<pre>`.

Comment: Additionally, you should also use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`, since the text could "accidentaly" contain HTML tags.

Comment: @awwrip you're welcome ! I've found out that it's the `white-space:pre` CSS attribute which matters and I've added an answer that provides this solution along other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current content of your `client.responseText` is something like the following :

```
log1
log2
log3
```

where linefeeds are `\n` or some other line terminator depending on the source OS.

Since you're overwriting the innerHTML of your `<p>` with that data, it produces this HTML :

```
<p>log1
log2
log3</p>
```

where the `\n` linefeed are meaningless and won't be rendered.

You have two options to achieve your goal :

- reformat the data so that it contains "HTML linefeeds". Ideally that would mean multiple `<p>` contained in a `<div>`, or probably better multiple `<li>` contained in a `<ul>` Using `<br/>` tags at the end of each line is another alternative. You can reformat the data using regex, e.g. `input.replace(/^.*$/mg, "<li>$&</li>")` which creates a `<li>` for each line
- make the `\n` linefeeds matter. This can be achieved by specifying the `white-space: preserve` CSS attribute, which is set by default for `<pre>` tags.